# Call base method on generic object of derived class

Tags: java, class, generics, multiple-inheritance

Trying to add a base interface with method so all derived classes have to implement the method or use default method. What's the best way to going about getting this method callable? See comment in code block below.

```
public interface IA{}  

public interface IB{   
  public Integer doWork();  
}  

public interface IC extends IB{
}

class B implements IB{
  Integer doWork(){
     return 2;
  }
}

class C extends B implements IC{
   @Override
   Integer doWork(){
     return 7;
  }
}

//What do I need to do to cast clazz to an object so I can call the derived class' doWork method?
private Integer newClient(Class<T> clazz){
  ((B) clazz).doWork();
}
```

Comment: A [`Class<T>` object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a class descriptor not an `Object` of said class.

Answer (score 1):

Ended up finding a solution:

```
B.class.cast(clazz);
```

Answer (score 0):

As for how to ensure you call the derived class' method that overrides the base, that is a native behavior of Java.

Example Program:

```
public class Foo {
    static class A {
        int get() { return 0; }
    }

    static class B extends A {
        @Override
        int get() { return 1; }
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        B b1 = new B();
        A b2 = new B();

        printA(a);
        printA(b1);
        printA(b2);
    }

    public static <T extends A> void printA(T bObj) {
        System.out.println(bObj.get());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
1
```

Note that the output returned from b2::get()::int is the same as b1::get()::int, even though b2 is type A and b1 is type B. This is because even though we only have a reference to the A class in b2, the object implementation is still B.

Comment: I'm looking more at how to make it callable in a situation like the last method in the code block. I'm aware of the override annotation.

Comment: You are already doing it. If the class you pass in is type C, you can cast clazz to class type B (though I would add an instanceof check if you don't want to limit the type of class to those that extend B or implement IB), then the call will call the C class' implementation of the function, even though you only cast it to class type B.

Comment: I'm sorry, I overlooked what @ Powerlord pointed out. I've edited my response to include the example of what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you only want to know how to instantiate the Class. Assuming it has a default constructor you can do it this way:

```
private Integer newClient(Class<B> clazz){
   try {
      ((B) (clazz.getConstructor().newInstance())).doWork();
    } catch ...
}
```